# Where is stacktrace file located for Android application when it crashes?

Tags: android, proguard

Where an Android app crashes and its not in debug mode, where can I retrieve the stacktrace?

Comment: There are many app in Google Paly that can help you retrieve log directly on device like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&hl=en), sometimes become handy.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on your device?

I assume since your retrieving it you own it. Plug the device into the computer and via adb

issue

```
adb logcat > log.txt
```

(log.txt will be filled with a logcat of all stack traces and recent events). Hit CTRL C after about 10 seconds of data collection.

Comment: I am interested to retrieve when not in debug mode.

Comment: I want to check that check retrace of proguard obfuscated code which is not available in debug mode.

Comment: Then you'll have to find an application on the market then to retrieve it. They don't make it easier to retrieve these unless you are in debug mode.